# Truffle Migrate base fee exceeds gas limit

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

While trying to deploy contracts locally I am getting the below error.

```
Error: *** Deployment Failed ***
"ABCContract" -- Returned error: base fee exceeds gas limit.
```

I have tried to manipulate the gas in Ganache GUI but this error is still occurring. Below is my truffle config.

```
require('babel-register')
require('babel-polyfill')

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 7545,
      network_id: '*', // Match any network id
    },
  },
  contracts_directory: './src/contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: '0.8.9',
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
      evmVersion: 'petersburg',
    },
  },
}
```

In Ganache I have set **GAS LIMIT: 6721975** and **GAS PRICE: 20000000000**

**UPDATE**

It turns out that if I remove some of my methods I am able to deploy the contract but apart from that I am getting the above error.

**Another Update**

I got the main reason why this error is occurring. It is because I am using mint function in my constructor and that mint is causing this problem. When I commented that function the problem is solved. Don't know why but it is causing the problem.

**Last and final update**

Turns out it was a programming mistake. I called the mint function inside the mint function instead of the ERC _mint function and it goes into recursion forever which caused this problem.

Comment: Can you try it with `evmVersion: 'london'`?

Comment: I tried it but no luck. @OliverTale-Yazdi

Comment: You could also set the gas price to 0, maybe that helps. Btw. did you update your truffle?

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this as well but still no luck. I also tried to specify gas in my truffle config same as in ganache but still the error is occurring. But this time the following error occurred:

`Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: stack overflow.`

Apart from this if I change nothing and remove some of the methods in my contract then I am not getting the error. Is there a limit for a smart contract to have limited methods or lines of code?

Comment: There is a maximum size of bytecode for a contract, but I don't think that you are hitting this. Solc would also warn you. I never had a `stackoverflow` in truffle or ganache. Not sure what is happening, can't help you more than suggesting to update everything.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi Thank you for the suggestion. I got the main reason why this error is occurring. It is because I am using mint function in my constructor and that mint is causing this problem. Don't know why but it is causing the problem. Do you know why it could be happening.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi Thank you for the answers. Turns out it was a programming mistake. I called the mint function inside the mint function instead of the ERC _mint function and it goes into recursion forever which caused this problem. Sorry for wasting you time :)